# Calling a stored procedure on live database using Laravel 5.5 is throwing memory error

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.5

I am using a laravel 5.5 and calling a stored proc which is working fine on my localhost with local DB. But throwing an error when I am trying to use on live server.

Stored proc is accepting 2 params as shown below in code.

```
$bidPlacedStats_ = DB::select('call getBidStatDayWise(?,?)',[$userId_,0]);
```

Error

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   318783264 bytes)

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this issue with following line of codes before calling the stored procedure.

> $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
>
> $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

Reference : [Link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/calling-stored-procedure-from-laravel-53-application-results-in-uncaught-pdo-exception)